# How to use a Fetch request from xcdatamodeld?

Tags: ios, core-data, request, swift3, nsfetchrequest

I'm noob with Core Data and I can't find the help I need on the Apple developer website.

I defined a fetch request in my `.xcdatamodeld` file but now I can't find how to use it?
This is the definition of the fetch request :
[image]

I supose that the fetch request starts with :

```
let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Category")
```

But I don't know how to use a fetch request by name.
(The project is written in Swift 3)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bharath's answer is for how to create and execute a fetch request in code. This is commonly how you'll do it. However, it's not actually the answer to your question. If you actually create a fetch request named "allCategories" in the core data model like that, this is how you use it:

```
let fetchRequest = self.managedObjectModel.fetchRequestTemplate(forName: "allCategories")

let fetchedObjects = self.managedObjectContext.execute(fetchRequest!)
```

Comment: I don't think that there is anything wrong with this method. But it isn't well documented. I have only seen this mentioned once.

Comment: Reference to other answer should be deleted since said answer has also been deleted. Also, your code assumes that the managedObjectModel has already been defined in this class. Better answer here imho: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391310/access-fetchrequest-from-xcdatamodel-in-ios

Answer (score -2):

If you had created an entity Users and inside it, you have created username and password. The fetch request for this will be the below code:

```
let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)      
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext     
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false    
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@ AND password = %@", username1.text!, password1.text!)   
let results:NSArray = try! context.executeFetchRequest(request)
```

Comment: Question is for using fetch request from Data Model!