# Access FetchRequest from xcdatamodel in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, xcdatamodel

I'm using NSPersistentContainer to access my core data in iOS10 app and Xcode 8.
Similar to Entity, I added a "UserFetchRequest" in my Coredata xcdatamodel. 
Below is the screen shot.

[image: Screen Shot]

How can I access the "UserFetchRequest" in the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having given your fetch request a name in the Data Model Inspector on the right hand side:

[image: Data Model Editor]

(in my case named "randomFetch" where yours is "UserFetchRequest"), get the model from the persistentContainer:

```
let model = persistentContainer.managedObjectModel
```

and then access the fetch request using the `fetchRequestTemplate(forName:)` method:

```
let fetchRequest = model.fetchRequestTemplate(forName: "randomFetch") as! NSFetchRequest<Event>
```

You can then execute this fetch request as normal.